# LazyStruct: Extra bytes detected at the end of the row! Ignoring similar problems

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I'm developing code in SQL spark reading tables in Hive ( HDFS ) .

The problem is that when I load my code in the shell of spark, recursively me the following message :

"WARN LazyStruct: Extra bytes detected at the end of the row! Ignoring similar problems."

I run the code that is:

```
val query_fare_details = sql("""
  SELECT *
  FROM fare_details
  WHERE fardet_cd_carrier = 'LA'
   AND fardet_cd_origin_city = 'SCL'
   AND fardet_cd_dest_city = 'MIA'
   AND fardet_cd_fare_basis = 'NNE0F0O1'
  """)
 query_fare_details.registerTempTable("query_fare_details")

val matchFAR1 = sql("""
  SELECT *
  FROM query_fare_details f
  JOIN fare_rules r ON f.fardet_cd_carrier = r.farrul_cd_carrier 
    AND f.fardet_num_rule_tariff = r.farrul_num_rule_tariff
    AND f.fardet_cd_fare_rule_bigint = r.farrul_cd_fare_rule_bigint
    AND f.fardet_cd_fare_basis = r.farrul_cd_fare_basis
  LIMIT 10""")

matchFAR1.show(5)
```

Any idea what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you can safely ignore this warning.  This is not an error

Refer [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3057][1]